# Executing a bash script from a remote server PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to run a bash script from a remote server and output the results from the server back to my html/php page so the user can see the output. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

include 'res/php/functions.php';
$gateway = 'remoteserver';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';

function cleanInput($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

//when the submit button is clicked
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 //$gateway = cleanInput($_POST['gateway']);

  //create the ssh connection
if ($connection = @ssh2_connect($gateway, 22)) {
       ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $pass);

       if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 1) { 
            $output = 
             shell_exec("/tmp/testscripts/up.sh");
       }

       if(isset($_POST['option'])  && $_POST['option'] == 2) { 
            $output = 
             shell_exec("/tmp/testscripts/down.sh");
       }
       //remove  this  if you want to see $output in this file

       echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
 }

} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. See the following.

```
           $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/tmp/moslehpour/testscripts/up.sh");
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
                echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);

           }

           if(isset($_POST['option'])  && $_POST['option'] == 2) { 
                $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/tmp/moslehpour/testscripts/down.sh");
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
                echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
           }
```